# flink - folds on keyed windows

Tags: java, apache-flink

Working with some data that I want to perform a fold on every 15 seconds. From the 'outside' it looks as if the window is holding all the data for the duration and then submitting it to the fold function all at once.

Truth?

If so, is there a way to have the fold function called every time a new piece of data is submitted and then *just the result* get returned at the end of the window?

Is there some other combination of transformations that could be put together to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct, yes. The reason is that the current implementation of the windowing operators is somewhat limited. Conceptually, there are two elements in a window operator: the *window buffer* and the *window function*. Let's assume the input type of the window operator is `IN` the output type is `OUT`. Now, the window buffer stores elements of type `IN` and when it comes time to emit elements it emits elements of type `IN`. The window function gets as input a collection of elements `IN` and emits elements of type `OUT` (`Collection[IN] -> OUT`).

If the window function is a reduce function we can pre-aggregate inside the window buffer since the signature of that is `(IN, IN) -> IN`. The window function basically only gets one element from the window buffer that it can emit.

If we want an efficient fold things get slightly more complex because we need the window buffer to take elements of type `IN` but emit type `OUT` and the window function to look like this: `OUT -> OUT`.

It is possible to do it but it's just not implemented that way right now. (By the way, I opened a Jira Issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-2991)